# Prevent different Nomad Jobs from running at the same time

Tags: job-scheduling, nomad

Is there a way to prevent different nomad jobs from running at the same time? Is there also a way to make a nomad job wait for another job to complete before it runs?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to prevent different nomad jobs from running at the same time?

No.

> Is there also a way to make a nomad job wait for another job to complete before it runs?

No. Only between two tasks https://developer.hashicorp.com/nomad/tutorials/task-deps/task-dependencies-interjob .

You have to implement such functionalities yourself. Which is why, in my company, we ended up with writing *out own scheduler above nomad*, which is very frustrating, to have this functionality. Consider using slurm.